# 1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have a site that randomly throws this JavaScript error. If you refresh the site it almost always occurs and it prevents the site from loading. Instead, you just see a blank white page.

The console states there is an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" in require.js on line 8. The line reads:

```
html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
```

Is there something wrong with this line that I'm not seeing?

[The site](http://sandbox.e-mc2.com/public/)

[Chrome console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNsuH.png)

[Firefox console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOx4n.png)

Comment: You need to post your code, not a link to a production site. You're going to fix the site when you get this question answered. We also expect a [mcve], so we don't have to go through all the code of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define("lib/config", [], function() {
    "use strict";
    var e = document.getElementById("app-config");
    return e ? JSON.parse(e.innerHTML) : {}
})
```

That's the problematic section of code. the app-config element isn't always loaded before this part is being executed. If possible, hard code your app-config into your html